# How can I hide the back button when authenticating to using Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I am using `Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplication` in my desktop application to authenticate the user using code like this:

```
        var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, TenantId)
            .WithRedirectUri(ReturnUri)
            .Build();

        var authenticationResult = await publicClientApplication
            .AcquireTokenInteractive(_defaultScopes)
            .WithParentActivityOrWindow(_ownerWindow)
            .ExecuteAsync();
```

At the moment I get a back button on the first page of the login UI - I'd like to remove this - does anyone know how?

UPDATE: Here is the Back button I am talking about

[image]

**This only seems to be a problem if we use https://login.microsoftonline.com - if we use https://login.windows.net then the branding is still there but the back button is not.**

Comment: What is the issue of leaving the back button there?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a button on the Microsoft UI, the answer is no. Limited customization is available through branding, app logos etc., but components of the UI cannot be modified.

Comment: Hi @juunas - I've updated my question to make it clearer. One thing which is odd (as I now mention above) is that the back button only appears if we go via https://login.microsoftonline.com (which we've just migrated to from https://login.windows.net) both show the branding at the top though.

Comment: Oh that's odd, didn't know that 

Comment: But I'm not aware of any parameters that would affect the visibility of the button.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, you are unable to control whether the Back button is shown on Microsoft's authentication flow. The back button is shown on all hosted views.